# Mutation kwargs in SQLAlchemy Column __init__

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a minimal Flask + SQLAlchemy application as follows:

```py
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import Column, INTEGER
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class CustomColumn(Column):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["default"] = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.comment = "My comment"


class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    my_column = CustomColumn()


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    id = Column("id", INTEGER(), primary_key=True)


app.run()
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
```

**Python version is 3.11.3**

Python get into the CustomColumn `__init__` twice while app starts. The first time, as expected, the `kwargs` were empty. Second time the `kwargs` are not empty (this can be seen by `kwargs["default"]`, `kwargs["comment"]` in debug mode).

I expect empty `kwargs` every time when Python get into CustomColumn `__init__`. More than that I don't understand even why CustomColumn `__init__` is calling twice.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method is called firstly for the `BaseModel` class and and secondly for the `MyModel` class, when the mapping process generates copies of inherited columns for subclasses.

The additional keyword arguments are the default arguments from the superclass's `__init__` signature.

There isn't an easy way to prevent these values being set (an it probably isn't advisable to do so). You can override them by passing your own values, a you have done with "default".